# How to Fetch SharedPrefernces value in Real-time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have notification details in `SharedPreferences` as `List<Notifications>`.  I want to get the **length**  of the list in real-time and update the UI.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
Future countNotifications() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final notificationsString = prefs.getString('notifications');

    List<Notifications>? notifications;

    // Decode the JSON string if it exists
    if (notificationsString != null) {
      notifications = (jsonDecode(notificationsString) as List)
          .map((e) => Notifications.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
    }

    return notifications!.length;
  }
```

I know this function does not give real-time data. How to make it receive data in real-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no live-update in shared_preferences. So there are several way to achieve what you want.

1. You can use one of the packages, which provide such functionality: [streaming_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/streaming_shared_preferences) or [rx_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/rx_shared_preferences). Both are streamed wrappers for classic shared preferences.
2. You can write your own wrapper for shared preference, which will notify on each change in your shared prefs (like in the packages above). The main idea is to create notification of changes when you save value and then to listen to the changes (you can see examples in the source code of the above packages).
3. You can use some other solution, which has streams/live-update like [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) instead of shared preferences to store your data locally.

Answer (score 0):

Please stop reconstructing the instance of SharedPreferences all over your code.  Initialize it once:

```
late final SharedPreferences prefs;
main() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // rest of main, including runApp
}
```

And now every get is synchronous:

```
final notificationsString = prefs.getString('notifications');
```

It's the "set" actions that are still async.  But get is sync!

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Please make an answer to show the length of the list in `Text()`.

Comment: The rest of your code is fine.  Just move prefs initialization to main, then remove "async" from your function.

Comment: did as u said.it gives. `LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.`

Comment: That's not possible.  The code runs in main before any of your code runs.